# Atlassian Bamboo: Triggering a build without pulling the mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, bamboo

Is it possible on Atlassian Bamboo to check if an update was made on a mercurial repository and trigger a build without pulling all the source code?

I mean, I only need to launch a deploy file that pulls the source directly on the server, so I do not need to pull it on my machine. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Atlassian Bamboo Documentation for this Case:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Repository+Triggers+the+Build+when+Changes+are+Committed

you can add a post commit trigger to your mercurial by add a line of code in
.hg/hgrcsettings

```
triggerName change-commit //myDepot/... "/usr/local/bin/postCommitBuildTrigger.sh http://bambooServer/ MYPLAN-DEFAULT"
```

Atlassian provide a script repo where you can get the postCommitBuildTrigger.sh  script.
http://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/9961886/scripts.zip

Greetz,
Phillip